# racket - define-syntax-class with pattern matching procedure

Tags: racket

I'm tring to define syntax class matching a parameter which is procedure.

I know how to match identifiers, expressions, another syntax classes.

This is my sample:

```
(define-syntax-class model-property
    #:description "a model property"
    #:attributes (name datatype guard)
    (pattern name:id
             #:with datatype #`null
             #:with guard #'(lambda (value) value)
             )
    (pattern [name:id #:datatype [datatype:id #:not-null] #:guard guard:expr])
    )
```

And I'd like to replace `#:guard guard:expr` with something like `#:guard guard:procedure`

I experimented with

```
(define-syntax-class model-property-guard
 #:description "a property guard"
(pattern guard:expr
         #:fail-when (procedure? #'guard)
         "property guard should be procedure."))
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros run at compile-time, before the program is executed. You can’t, at compile-time, know what sort of value an expression will produce—the information simply doesn’t exist. (You could theoretically check such a thing in a language with a static type system, but `#lang racket` is dynamically typed.)

One thing you *can* do is put a contract on an expression so that it raises a runtime error if the contract isn’t matched. The [`expr/c` syntax class](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Library_Syntax_Classes_and_Literal_Sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._expr%2Fc%29%29) is provided for this purpose. You use it like this:

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax-class model-property-guard
    #:description "a property guard"
    (pattern (~var guard (expr/c #'procedure?))
             #:with c #'guard.c)))

(define-syntax (m stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ guard:model-property-guard)
     #'guard.c]))
```

Using the above definitions, writing `(m add1)` will successfully produce `#<procedure:add1>`, while writing `(m 1)` will fail at runtime with a contract violation:

```
m: contract violation
  expected: procedure?
  given: 1
  in: procedure?
```

Note that the expansion *must* use `guard.c` in the expansion! The `c` attribute contains a modified expression that attaches a contract to the value, and using `guard` directly would merely pass the expression through unchanged, without the contract attached.

For some more examples of `expr/c` in action, see [Contracts on Macro Sub-expressions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/exprc.html).